# Type mismatch in AutoHotkey Excel

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I am trying to get input from a user, lookup the input value in an Excel column and return the value of the cell on the right side of the matching value.

This is what I came up with. As long as I replace %index% with a number, it will return a value from the Excel file.

The error I receive tells me there is a 'type mismatch' where I use **%index%** in

```
value := workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(%index%, 1).Value
```

Any ideas how to fix the type mismatch?

```
#a::
workbook := ComObjGet("somepath\tester.xlsx")

InputBox, OutputVar, Question 1, What are you looking for?
if (OutputVar)
   MsgBox, Let me do this for you.
   intent = OutputVar

index = 1
value = ""

Loop {
    index := %index% + 1
    value := workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(%index%, 1).Value
}
Until %intent% = %value%

SendInput, workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(%index%, 2).Value

Return
```

Comment: I have a few comments. Do you know that you can do lookups and get values of adjacent cells right inside Excel? When outside of Excel, why not read the Excel columns into an AHK array and perform the lookups locally?

Answer (score 2):

Use `index`, not `%index%`, in expressions. Also, you can use the built-in [`A_INDEX`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) variable inside of loops

**Here's your corrected code:**

```
#a::
  workbook := ComObjGet("somepath\tester.xlsx")
  MAX_ROWS := 10

  InputBox intent, Question 1, What are you looking for?

  if ( ErrorLevel == 0 && intent ) {
    Loop %MAX_ROWS% {
      if ( intent == workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(A_Index, 1).Value ) {
         SendInput % workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(A_Index, 2).Value
         return
      }
    }
    MsgBox 48, Not Found, "%intent%" not found in column a
  }
  return
```

**Notes:**

- You cannot use substitution when a command takes an expression
- `ErrorLevel == 0` means OK was pressed. See [InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm)
- `SendInput %` makes the line use [expression mode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Variables); everything following "% " is evaluated as an expression
- Your loop never exits if `intent` is not found in the spreadsheet